# porting web browser application to mobile device

Tags: grails, mobile, groovy, httprequest

We have developed a Web Application using grails, groovy and oracle as database with css and javascript (jquery) and ajax for web related features. The application work fine on all desktop based web browsers like firefox, IE, chrome etc.
And for hosting it we use tomcat server.

Now we want to develop a mobile based version of this web application such that when the request comes from a mobile device the server should detect the type of device and route it or serve it using the appropriate instance (mobile one for mobile device and normal one for computers)
 How do I implement this check in request resolution? is this by creating my custom filter in tomcat server?

Also for the mobile instance I want to have the changes only in the views , its should use the same controllers and services and all other code used for the main browsers, just views and styles and js if required will change. how do I go about having different views for mobile version which get called automatically if the request is coming from a mobile device
Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [spring mobile plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-mobile)? The documentation seems to cover all your questions...

Comment: Thanks for the tip..in most of the professional websites I notice that accessing them from mobile device automatically reroutes to the mobile version which has a url like http://www.m.southwest.com for www.southwest.com or www.mobile.facebook.com for www.facebook.com, so these are different servers altoghether..?

Comment: THey could be different servers, or different webapps on the same server, or the serverURL could just be used to keep you on the same mobile path once they have detected mobile usage at the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/adding-mobile-views-to-your-grails-applications-with-jquery-mobile-a-real-life-example/) contains specific tips for porting a Grails web app to mobile